# retrieving children from parent container of a certain type

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flash-cs4

is it possible to retrieve all children of a certain type from a parent in actionscript 3?
i only see getChildAt,getChildByName, is there a getchild of a certain type like get all childs of object type:Food?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function getChildrenOfType( p_parent:DisplayObjectContainer, p_class:Class ):Array
{
    var result:Array = [];
    for( var i:0; i < p_parent.numChildren; ++i )
    {
        if( p_parent.getChildAt(i) is p_class )
        {
            result.push( p_parent.getChildAt(i);
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Might need some tweaking, but it would go something like that.

Answer (score 0):

you should try this:

p_parent.numChildren which gives you total number of children inside a movieclip.